# BeautifulSoup like scraper for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cheerio

I am former python developer and I have used BS4 for couple of years
Now I am developing with node and yes cheerio package is very good, but I need smth like BS4 for scraping in node

Is there some alternatives for cheerio? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest you check out the [x-ray node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray). It is essentially an abstraction layer above cheerio that makes the code you need to 'structure any website' even more terse.

It has a composable syntax in style and it supports pagination, limiting/throttling, delaying, scraping collections etc.

Comment: I have tried it, but it is not so good as cheerio

Comment: Probably useful for you to know that x-ray is built by the same author as cheerio, and he built x-ray after cheerio. Thus has a higher level of abstraction ;-)

Comment: X-ray combines HTTP request making and data extraction. In that sense, it is more similar to Scrappy than no BeautifulSoup. A closer library is https://github.com/gajus/surgeon.